# loop 0xb7 assembles but won't link

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86, ld

I have the following ASM code on Debian that I am trying to compile but am having issues with both `ld` and `gcc`.

uname -a: `Linux kali 4.18.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.18.20-2kali2 (2018-11-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I start off by running: `nasm -f elf shellcode.asm`

This completes with no issues.

GCC Issue...
Command: `gcc -m32 -o key shellcode.o`
Error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: shellcode.o: in function `_start':
shellcode.asm:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'; /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../lib32/Scrt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../lib32/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `main'
/usr/bin/ld: shellcode.o: in function `_start':
shellcode.asm:(.text+0xbc): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_PC8 against `*UND*'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also tried with `ld`.

Command: `ld -m elf_i386 -s -o key shellcode.o`

Error...

```
ld: shellcode.o: in function `_start':
shellcode.asm:(.text+0xbc): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_PC8 against `*UND*'
```

The latter appears to be less full of errors and point to an issue with the ASM syntaxt.

My question then is, which of these commands in the correct one to use and what am I doing wrong?

`shellcode.asm`

```
global _start
_start:
    xor eax,eax
    push eax
    push dword 0x76767975
    push dword 0x22717172
    push dword 0x22737972
    push dword 0x77207922
    push dword 0x78272079
    push dword 0x27277976
    push dword 0x77707470
    push dword 0x22777272
    push dword 0x22277622
    push dword 0x79727473
    push dword 0x27727377
    push dword 0x75747078
    push dword 0x70227479
    push dword 0x75222073
    push dword 0x24747176
    push dword 0x74782324
    push dword 0x72727320
    push dword 0x27762779
    push dword 0x20277777
    push dword 0x22207573
    push dword 0x70247827
    push dword 0x70277479
    push dword 0x24712379
    push dword 0x77742027
    push dword 0x76242379
    push dword 0x22702270
    push dword 0x73762577
    push dword 0x24752272
    push dword 0x20277172
    push dword 0x23712720
    push dword 0x72722478
    push dword 0x70252723
    push esp
    pop esi
    mov edi,esi
    mov edx,edi
    cld
    mov ecx,0x80
    mov ebx,0x41
    xor eax,eax
    push eax
    lodsb
    xor eax,ebx
    stosb
    loop 0xb7
    push esp
    pop esi
    int3
    db 0x0a
```

Comment: Why are you doing `loop 0xb7`. Place a label where you wish to loop back to and use the label with the `loop` instruction. That is the cause of the relocation error. It is a bit unclear what you are trying to do with the `loop` instruction in the first place.

Comment: You are assembling, not compiling. Compiling is used for higher level languages that get compiled into assembly which is then assembled into hex.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thanks for that. The code is part of a challenge to extract a secret key using gdb so this is just the sample that was provided. I will look at editing as you suggested

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, @Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build with gcc, you're defining `_start` not `main`, so you need to use `-nostdlib`.  Like `gcc -m32 -nostdlib -static -o key shellcode.o`.  That will make gcc invoke `ld` the way you did manually.

---

`loop` is only available with a rel8 displacement, so it can't reach absolute address `0xb7` from the much higher address where `ld` places it in the code segment.

***If* you actually did want to do that (but you almost certainly don't)**, you could use `dec ecx / jnz 0xb7`, which would use a `jcc rel32` encoding and thus can reach any absolute address via `EIP + rel32`.  Or use a linker script to link the TEXT segment at a very low virtual address so `loop rel8` can reach.

(But either way that's not position-independent.  Normally shellcode is supposed to work after being injected at an unknown address.  If you really wanted to jump to an absolute address in position-independent shellcode, like to trigger a specific page fault(?), you'd need the address in a register and use `jmp eax`)

---

But much more likely you wanted to jump to somewhere else *in your code*, not to some low absolute address. **Place a label on your branch target and use `dec ecx / jnz label`**.  (Or use the `loop` instruction since you're probably optimizing for code-size regardless of it being slow.)

---

If you borrowed this code from somewhere, maybe it was in an assembler where `loop 0xb7` set the value of the `rel8` displacement.  Or maybe it was NASM with `org 0x0` and `BITS 32` making a flat binary?  But it would make so much more sense just to use a label if you want to branch back into somewhere in this code.

Comment: That's great, I will check your suggestions out later today. Thanks!

Comment: Can you just clarify, is `dec ecx / jnz` a single instruction to be appended with a memory address? IE: `dec ecx / jnz 0xmyAddress`. Or should it be split out into it's component parts?

Comment: @RichC: It's 2 separate instructions, `dec` and `jnz.  If that's not obvious, consult an x86 instruction reference: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/index.html.  But they decode into a single uop on modern Intel CPUs.

Comment: Thanks, not sure what I was banging on about combining them as a single instruction! Thanks for the link, great reference