# x86 Assembly EIP Value not displaying in readable format

Tags: assembly, gdb, elf

I have a piece of assembly code that I am analyzing to extract a secret key.
The source code is below but what I am doing is setting a breakpoint after the `pop esp` instruction and then trying to examine the stack to ascertain a 128-bit key.

My assembly knowledge is still rudimentary but what I think is happening is the program constructs the key with the opening series of `DWORD` instructions and then loads it onto the stack.

The problem is the output. I break after the `pop esp` call, examine the stack, but is all 'scrambled'.

I think this is the string I want: `0xffffd21c ("#'%px$rr 'q#rq' r\"u$w%vsp\"p\"y#$v' twy#q$yt'p'x$psu \"ww' y'v' srr$#xtvqt$s \"uyt\"pxptuwsr'stry\"v'\"rrw\"ptpwvy''y 'x\"y wrys\"rqq\"uyvv")`

My question is, is my understanding of the execution wrong and why? How can I correct my process to extract the human readable string from the garbled characters at `esp`?

My output from GDB/PEDA...

```
root@kali:~/ctp/challenge# gdb ./key 
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.2
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./key...done.
gdb-peda$ break *0x565560a4
Breakpoint 1 at 0x565560a4
gdb-peda$ r
Starting program: /root/ctp/challenge/key 



[----------------------------------registers-----------------------------------]
EAX: 0x0 
EBX: 0xf7ffd000 --> 0x28f2c 
ECX: 0x0 
EDX: 0xf7fe4560 (push   ebp)
ESI: 0xffffd2ac --> 0xffffd468 ("SHELL=/bin/bash")
EDI: 0x56556000 (<_start>:  xor    eax,eax)
EBP: 0x0 
ESP: 0xffffd218 --> 0xffffd21c ("#'%px$rr 'q#rq' r\"u$w%vsp\"p\"y#$v' twy#q$yt'p'x$psu \"ww' y'v' srr$#xtvqt$s \"uyt\"pxptuwsr'stry\"v'\"rrw\"ptpwvy''y 'x\"y wrys\"rqq\"uyvv")
EIP: 0x565560a4 (<_start+164>:  pop    esi)
EFLAGS: 0x246 (carry PARITY adjust ZERO sign trap INTERRUPT direction overflow)
[-------------------------------------code-------------------------------------]
   0x56556099 <_start+153>: push   0x72722478
   0x5655609e <_start+158>: push   0x70252723
   0x565560a3 <_start+163>: push   esp
=> 0x565560a4 <_start+164>: pop    esi
   0x565560a5 <_start+165>: mov    edi,esi
   0x565560a7 <_start+167>: mov    edx,edi
   0x565560a9 <_start+169>: cld    
   0x565560aa <_start+170>: mov    ecx,0x80
[------------------------------------stack-------------------------------------]
0000| 0xffffd218 --> 0xffffd21c ("#'%px$rr 'q#rq' r\"u$w%vsp\"p\"y#$v' twy#q$yt'p'x$psu \"ww' y'v' srr$#xtvqt$s \"uyt\"pxptuwsr'stry\"v'\"rrw\"ptpwvy''y 'x\"y wrys\"rqq\"uyvv")
0004| 0xffffd21c ("#'%px$rr 'q#rq' r\"u$w%vsp\"p\"y#$v' twy#q$yt'p'x$psu \"ww' y'v' srr$#xtvqt$s \"uyt\"pxptuwsr'stry\"v'\"rrw\"ptpwvy''y 'x\"y wrys\"rqq\"uyvv")
0008| 0xffffd220 ("x$rr 'q#rq' r\"u$w%vsp\"p\"y#$v' twy#q$yt'p'x$psu \"ww' y'v' srr$#xtvqt$s \"uyt\"pxptuwsr'stry\"v'\"rrw\"ptpwvy''y 'x\"y wrys\"rqq\"uyvv")
0012| 0xffffd224 (" 'q#rq' r\"u$w%vsp\"p\"y#$v' twy#q$yt'p'x$psu \"ww' y'v' srr$#xtvqt$s \"uyt\"pxptuwsr'stry\"v'\"rrw\"ptpwvy''y 'x\"y wrys\"rqq\"uyvv")
0016| 0xffffd228 ("rq' r\"u$w%vsp\"p\"y#$v' twy#q$yt'p'x$psu \"ww' y'v' srr$#xtvqt$s \"uyt\"pxptuwsr'stry\"v'\"rrw\"ptpwvy''y 'x\"y wrys\"rqq\"uyvv")
0020| 0xffffd22c ("r\"u$w%vsp\"p\"y#$v' twy#q$yt'p'x$psu \"ww' y'v' srr$#xtvqt$s \"uyt\"pxptuwsr'stry\"v'\"rrw\"ptpwvy''y 'x\"y wrys\"rqq\"uyvv")
0024| 0xffffd230 ("w%vsp\"p\"y#$v' twy#q$yt'p'x$psu \"ww' y'v' srr$#xtvqt$s \"uyt\"pxptuwsr'stry\"v'\"rrw\"ptpwvy''y 'x\"y wrys\"rqq\"uyvv")
0028| 0xffffd234 ("p\"p\"y#$v' twy#q$yt'p'x$psu \"ww' y'v' srr$#xtvqt$s \"uyt\"pxptuwsr'stry\"v'\"rrw\"ptpwvy''y 'x\"y wrys\"rqq\"uyvv")
[------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
Legend: code, data, rodata, value

Breakpoint 1, 0x565560a4 in _start ()
gdb-peda$ x/10s $esp
0xffffd218: "\034\322\377\377#'%px$rr 'q#rq' r\"u$w%vsp\"p\"y#$v' twy#q$yt'p'x$psu \"ww' y'v' srr$#xtvqt$s \"uyt\"pxptuwsr'stry\"v'\"rrw\"ptpwvy''y 'x\"y wrys\"rqq\"uyvv"
0xffffd29d: ""
0xffffd29e: ""
0xffffd29f: ""
0xffffd2a0: "\001"
0xffffd2a2: ""
0xffffd2a3: ""
0xffffd2a4: "P\324\377\377"
0xffffd2a9: ""
0xffffd2aa: ""
gdb-peda$
```

Code...

```
global _start
_start:
    xor eax,eax
    push eax
    push dword 0x76767975
    push dword 0x22717172
    push dword 0x22737972
    push dword 0x77207922
    push dword 0x78272079
    push dword 0x27277976
    push dword 0x77707470
    push dword 0x22777272
    push dword 0x22277622
    push dword 0x79727473
    push dword 0x27727377
    push dword 0x75747078
    push dword 0x70227479
    push dword 0x75222073
    push dword 0x24747176
    push dword 0x74782324
    push dword 0x72727320
    push dword 0x27762779
    push dword 0x20277777
    push dword 0x22207573
    push dword 0x70247827
    push dword 0x70277479
    push dword 0x24712379
    push dword 0x77742027
    push dword 0x76242379
    push dword 0x22702270
    push dword 0x73762577
    push dword 0x24752272
    push dword 0x20277172
    push dword 0x23712720
    push dword 0x72722478
    push dword 0x70252723
    push esp
    pop esi
    mov edi,esi
    mov edx,edi
    cld
    mov ecx,0x80
    mov ebx,0x41
    xor eax,eax
    push eax
    lodsb
    xor eax,ebx
    stosb
    ;loop 0xb7 ; offending line
    ;dec ecx
    jnz 0xb7; added in
    push esp
    pop esi
    int3
    db 0x0a
```

Comment: Not sure what version of the code you are running. With **both** the `loop` and the `dec ecx` commented out the code will not process the string just the first character. On second thought, it will depend on the `xor` result which is unlikely what you want anyway.

Comment: Also, apparently you didn't understand the comments and my answer on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56049868/loop-0xb7-assembles-but-wont-link).  You don't *actually* want `jnz 0xb7`, that will jump to absolute address `0xb7` and segfault.  I pointed that out as a way to illustrate the meaning of what you wrote, and how assembling + linking works.

Comment: This looks like it's supposed to be just a dumb loop that XORs 0x80 bytes with `0x41`.  Could obviously be done much more efficiently with `xor dword [esi], 0x41414141` / `add esi, 4` in a loop, or with slightly smaller code size golfing a different way (e.g. with `lodsd` to increment ESI).  The loop makes me think optimizing for code-size, but then `mov ecx, imm32` is strong evidence against that.  Amusing point that `jnz` will always be taken because XOR will always produce a non-zero result with that data.

Comment: They aren't garbled, those are (presumably) the correct interpretation of those bytes as ASCII characters.  You said you want EIP values (which is exploit speak for return addresses even when they're *not* in EIP...),  But it looks like string data.  e.g. `0x70 ^ 0x41 = 0x31 = '1'`. and `0x23^0x41 = 0x62 = 'b'`.  The actual EIP display is fine: `EIP: 0x565560a4 (<_start+164>: pop esi)`.  If the stack did hold return addresses, you'd use `x /10xw $esp` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't garbled, those are (presumably) the correct interpretation of those bytes as ASCII characters.

And **they aren't an EIP value or values**.  ("EIP value" is sometimes exploit speak for return addresses even when they're *not* in EIP, but I don't think that's going on here).  The actual EIP display is fine: `EIP: 0x565560a4 (<_start+164>: pop esi)`.

If the stack did hold return addresses, you'd use `x /10xw $esp` or similar.

It looks like string data.  e.g. `0x70 ^ 0x41 = 0x31 = '1'`. and `0x23^0x41 = 0x62 = 'b'`.

> But what I think is happening is the program constructs the key with the opening series of DWORD instructions and then loads it onto the stack.

No, it constructs the *data* on the stack with a series of pushes.  It's *already* on the stack at that point.

**The key is `0x41`, in `mov ebx, 0x41`.**

---

Then it looks like it has an inefficient loop that should `xor` every byte one at a time with `0x41`, but you commented out the `dec` and left in the branch to an absolute address of `0xb7` which will segfault under Linux.

Pretty obviously it's supposed to be

```
.loop:            ; do {
   lodsb
   xor  eax,ebx
   stosb
   dec  ecx
   jnz  .loop     ; }while(--ecx);
```

after the earlier instructions that set up EDI and ESI = ESP, and clear DF to string instructions go upward.

This is hilariously inefficient (going 1 byte at a time for ECX = 0x80 bytes and using the slow `loop` instruction which limits it to 1 iteration per 6 cycles on recent Intel CPUs), but also doesn't look optimized for code-size.  (`mov eax, 0x41` is 5 bytes vs. 3 for `push 0x41` / `pop eax`).  Optimizing the loop for code-size but the code *outside* for speed is backwards.

Much more efficient would be `xor dword [esi], 0x41414141` / `add esi,4`.  (Or you could use `lodsd` as a 1-byte way to increment ESI by 4 if you care about code-size not speed.)

Comment: I will test that when I get home. Apologies, i misunderstood what you meant by a label previously. I thought `label == memory address` rather than an actual label for the loop 'area'. Also the `dec ecx` instruction, am I right in that it is decrementing ecx (counter) which `jnz` is then assessing for the loop continue/break out?

Comment: @RichC: No, `jnz` reads ZF in EFLAGS.  (which `dec ecx` sets according to the result of `--ecx`).  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/index.html.  Or look up any decent tutorial or book on how x86 asm branches and loops work.

Comment: With ZF in EFLAGS being 'reset' with `cld`?

Then...

String loaded into `eax` with this set? `push eax / lodsb / xor eax,ebx / stosb`. push, eax, load string into eax, xor operation with 0x41 and then store the string.

What I can't see is where the final collected string of length 0x80 is being stored.

Sorry for the thousand questions, just trying to make sure I understand properly!

Comment: @RichC: No, `cld` clears DF.  ZF is one of the condition-code flags.  Again, look up any decent tutorial or documentation on x86 flags and branching. I''m not sure what the point of pushing an extra dword of zeros before the loop is.  (But it's after setting ESI and EDI, so it's not part of what the loop processes.)  And note that `lodsb` only loads into AL.  Anyway, the string is *already* saved on the stack, it's just being modified in place.  Single-step the code with a debugger, and watch register values change.  e.g. `gdb` with `layout reg`, or whatever you prefer.